# VTK Structured Point file

Tags: c, vtk, voxel, paraview

I am trying to parse a VTK file in C by extracting its point data and storing each point in a 3D array. However, the file I am working with has 9 shorts per point and I am having difficulty understanding what each number means.

I believe I understand most of the header information (please correct me if I have misunderstood):

- ASCII: Type of file (ASCII or Binary)
- DATASET: Type of dataset
- DIMENSIONS: dims of voxels (x,y,z)
- SPACING: Volume of each voxel (w,h,d)
- ORIGIN: Unsure
- POINT DATA: Total number of points/voxels (dimx.dimy.dimz)

I have looked at the documentation and I am still not getting an understanding on how to interpret the data. Could someone please help me understand or point me to some helpful resources

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS
DIMENSIONS 256 256 130
SPACING 1 1 1.3
ORIGIN 86.6449 -133.929 116.786
POINT_DATA 8519680
SCALARS scalars short
LOOKUP_TABLE default
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 7 2 4 5 3 3 4 
4 5 5 1 7 7 1 1 2 
1 6 4 3 3 1 0 4 2 
2 3 2 4 2 2 0 2 6 
...
```

thanks.

Comment: since you tagged paraview, you can use the software as reference to see what the file represents (open the file - click the apply button - then in the principal window open a new "spreadsheet" view), as a spreadsheet you see which are the points and the data associated to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct regarding the meaning of fields in the header.
`ORIGIN` corresponds to the coordinates of the 0-0-0 corner of the grid. 
An example of a `DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS` can be found in the [documentation](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf).

Starting from this, here is a small file with 6 shorts per point. Each line represents a point.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Volume example
ASCII
DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS
DIMENSIONS 3 4 2
ASPECT_RATIO 1 1 1
ORIGIN 0 0 0
POINT_DATA 24
SCALARS volume_scalars char 6
LOOKUP_TABLE default
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 2 3 4 5
0 2 2 3 4 5
1 2 2 3 4 5
2 2 2 3 4 5
0 3 2 8 9 10
1 3 2 8 9 10
2 3 2 8 9 10
0 4 2 8 9 10
1 4 2 8 9 10
2 4 2 8 9 10
0 1 3 18 19 20
1 1 3 18 19 20
2 1 3 18 19 20
0 2 3 18 19 20
1 2 3 18 19 20
2 2 3 18 19 20
0 3 3 24 25 26
1 3 3 24 25 26
2 3 3 24 25 26
0 4 3 24 25 26
1 4 3 24 25 26
2 4 3 24 25 26
```

The 3 first fields may be displayed to understand the data layout : x change faster than y, which change faster than z in file.

If you wish to store the data in an array `a[2][4][3][6]`, just read while doing a loop :

```
for(k=0;k<2;k++){ //z loop  
  for(j=0;j<4;j++){ //y loop : y change faster than z
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){ //x loop : x change faster than y 
      for(l=0;l<6;l++){
         fscanf(file,"%d",&a[k][j][i][l]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To read the header, [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) may be used as well :

```
int sizex,sizey,sizez;
char headerpart[100];
fscanf(file,"%s",headerpart);
if(strcmp(headerpart,"DIMENSIONS")==0){
   fscanf(file,"%d%d%d",&sizex,&sizey,&sizez);
}
```

Note than `fscanf()` need the pointer to the data (`&sizex`, not `sizex`). A string being a pointer to an array of char terminated by `\0`, `"%s",headerpart` works fine. It can be replaced by `"%s",&headerpart[0]`. The function [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) compares two strings, and return `0` if strings are identical.

As your grid seems large, smaller files can be obtained using the `BINARY` kind instead of `ASCII`, but watch for [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377028/are-vtk-files-endian-independent-when-read-in-visualization-softwares-such-as-pa).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the fscanf method is great also (was using strtok_r to split each line up!). How would I use fscanf to split up the header efficiently (to use store the dims in a struct for example). Also (I am new to voxels) so how do the points relate to a co-ordinate? can you give an example I could visualise?